# getting RDF element values (rdf:Description, rdf:about) from a OWL file using jena API (java)

Tags: rdf, jena, owl

I am looking for a way how to get the values of rdf attributes (rdf:about, rdf:parseType, rdf:Description) from the below OWL class.

I am using JENA java API, but I cant see any API to get these RDF attributes or tag values.

I will be glad if you can help me out regarding this

```
 <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#SpicyPizzaEquivalent">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Pizza"/>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasTopping"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom>
                        <owl:Class>
                            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                                <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#PizzaTopping"/>
                                <owl:Restriction>
                                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasSpiciness"/>
                                    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Hot"/>
                                </owl:Restriction>
                            </owl:intersectionOf>
                        </owl:Class>
                    </owl:someValuesFrom>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">An alternative definition for the SpicyPizza which does away with needing a definition of SpicyTopping and uses a slightly more complicated restriction: Pizzas that have at least one topping that is both a PizzaTopping and has spiciness hot are members of this class.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="pt">PizzaTemperadaEquivalente</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">SpicyPizzaEquivalent</rdfs:label>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Spicy Pizza Equivalent</skos:prefLabel>
</owl:Class>
```

Comment: `rdf:about, rdf:parseType, rdf:Description``are part of the XML serialization of RDF and have nothing to do with the information of RDF itself despite its encoding. Apache Jena is an API primarily for RDF with some support for at least OWL 1. It's not clear what you want to get, thus, I'd suggest to look at this from an OWL perspective and clarify what you want. As a hint, your current snippet shows an equivalent classes axiom for a given class.

Comment: What @AKSW said is correct. You need to think about your data in terms of RDF triples and/or OWL classes and properties, not in terms of xml syntax. Once you start doing that, querying it with Jena becomes a lot more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your response @AKSW and Jeen.

Comment: I want to get to know to what the "equivalent class is matching to", and this I can only get from the rdf:Description tags rdf:about attribute.I use below code but I am unable to get the equivalent class name
` OntClass equivalentClass = cls.getEquivalentClass();
 Property intersectionOfProperty = ontModel.createProperty("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#intersectionOf");
 Statement intersectionOfPropertyStatement = equivalentClass.getProperty(intersectionOfProperty);  
`

Comment: What do you mean by "the equivalent class name"? Please understand the original axiom: `SpicyPizzaEquivalent EquivalentTo (Pizza and hasTopping some (PizzaTopping and hasSpiciness some Hot))`   `cls` should be the class `SpicyPizzaEquivalent`. The other "side" is the complex OWL class expression `Pizza and hasTopping some (PizzaTopping and hasSpiciness some Hot)` So, you want to get what?

Comment: By the way, Jena is focused on RDF. You're trying to process an OWL axiom which is made of a collection of RDF triples. IS it necessary to use Jena? Otherwise, there is the OWL API whose datastructures correspond to the OWL constructs.

Comment: Thanks @AKSW. I would atleast need to fetch this expression, using Jena API :  '(Pizza and hasTopping some (PizzaTopping and hasSpiciness some Hot)) ' But I see that it is not so easy to get the above content using Jena API on equivalentClass. `I still` rely on this snippet, but once I have the Statement object for *intersectionOf* -> I am unable to traverse it further `Statement intersectionOfPropertyStatement = equivalentClass.getProperty(intersectionOfProperty);`

Comment: Please don't work on the RDF layer when processing OWL constructs. Jena has an ontology layer, in particular what you need is [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/#more-complex-class-expressions)

Comment: Super. @AKSW Thanks a lot for the information. This is what I was exactly looking for